# Mysql innerjoin search in php

Tags: php, mysql, search

Here is my select query

```
 $raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT *,student_data.student_id,student_data.image,student_data.firstname, student_data.middleI,
            student_data.lastname, 
            student_data.address, student_data.birthday,
            section.section_name, department.dept_name, year_graduated.year, course.course_name,
            year_graduated.publish_id  FROM student_data        
    INNER JOIN course ON student_data.course_id=course.course_id
    INNER JOIN section ON student_data.section_id=section.section_id
    INNER JOIN department ON student_data.dept_id=department.dept_id
    INNER JOIN year_graduated ON student_data.year_id=year_graduated.year_id WHERE (`firstname` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`lastname` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`birthday` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`section_name` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`course_name` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`year` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`address` LIKE '%".$query."%') AND publish_id=2")  ;
```

I want to show only the student_data with year_graduated.publish_id is equal to 2. When i run the above code, it does not filter the publish_id of the students.

Comment: i only want to display the data that has the publish id = 2. but my query display all data even the publish data is not equal to 2 :(

Answer (score 2):

I think there is a mistake with brackets.
Put opening before (`firstname` LIKE '%".$query."%') and closing before AND AND publish_id=2

Like that

```
$raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT *,student_data.student_id,student_data.image,student_data.firstname, student_data.middleI,
            student_data.lastname, 
            student_data.address, student_data.birthday,
            section.section_name, department.dept_name, year_graduated.year, course.course_name,
            year_graduated.publish_id  FROM student_data        
    INNER JOIN course ON student_data.course_id=course.course_id
    INNER JOIN section ON student_data.section_id=section.section_id
    INNER JOIN department ON student_data.dept_id=department.dept_id
    INNER JOIN year_graduated ON student_data.year_id=year_graduated.year_id WHERE ((`firstname` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`lastname` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`birthday` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`section_name` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`course_name` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`year` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`address` LIKE '%".$query."%')) AND publish_id=2")
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're running a join operation in mysql you should put the table name or alias name before the find fields. Make sure that you have a valid table name before *

Please change your query like

```
SELECT table_name.*, student_data.student_id ...
```

And please put table / alias name before the find fields. Like

```
WHERE (`student_data.firstname` LIKE '%".$query."%')
```

OR

```
AND year_graduated.publish_id = 2
```